# I am getting error Unfortunately app has stopped.Where is the mistake?

Tags: java, android, xml

These are the sections of code mentioned.As I run these errors pop up in logcat file and the app crashes when opened.There are so many of them that I could not figure out where the actual mistake is.Please Help me out where there is need of modification and replacement as I am trying to build a splash screen.

logcat:

```
06-08 11:36:18.203 17265-17265/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.elvero.telecom.voipapp, PID: 17265
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.elvero.telecom.voipapp/com.elvero.telecom.voipapp.splash}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1515)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5717)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                       at com.elvero.telecom.voipapp.splash.onCreate(splash.java:13)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2514)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1515) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5717) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x6
                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelOffset(TypedArray.java:533)
                                                       at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3927)
                                                       at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:139)
                                                       at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:60)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:56)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087)
                                                       at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                       at com.elvero.telecom.voipapp.splash.onCreate(splash.java:13) 
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092) 
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2514) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1515) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5717) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
06-08 11:36:22.207 17265-17265/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17265 SIG: 9
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.elvero.telecom.voipapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar= (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.elvero.telecom.voipapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

splashactivity:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:context="com.elvero.telecom.voipapp.splash">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:elevation="@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_elvero"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Splash.java:

```
package com.elvero.telecom.voipapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        Handler handler=new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                startActivity(new Intent(splash.this,MainActivity.class));
                finish();

            }
        },1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add code for your xml activity_main

Comment: Could you just keep necessary things in your imageView ? The stacktrace said Error inflating class ImageView just keep src and size attrribut drop the rest for testing purpose

Comment: problem with your imageview in xml

Comment: I think the problem is in this line: `android:elevation="@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor"`. Try changing the elevation value to some constant, and see if it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

error caused because code

```
android:elevation="@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor"
```

its better to give direct value to it like

```
android:elevation="5dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make separate Activity as a splash screen and use below code in onCreate() to show it for required seconds and then can move to your main landing activity.

```
new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            HarmUtils.openActivity(SplashScreenActivity.this, LoginActivity.class, true);
        }
    }.start();
```

here 2000 is waiting time (2000 = 2 seconds) and second parameter is time interval which I set to 1 second.
You can specify your time as per your requirements.

Hope this will help you.